# Implement a navigation property in c# class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

i have 2 entities each with a relating c# class. I set up a navigation property on **table A** to contain a reference to many items in **table B**.  When i make a new **table A class object** i need to be able to create the collection of **table B** objects in **table A**. How do i set up the navigation property in the **table A** c# class?

DATAMODEL:
http://bluewolftech.com/mike/mike/datamodel.jpg

Comment: Which version of the EF are you using?  Are you using Code First?  Do you have a model/diagram?

Comment: EF 4.0. yes using code first and im using an edmx file for the data model.

Comment: If you're using an EDMX, you're not using code first.  Code first is just POCO classes that are decorated with attributes.

Comment: If you are using EDMX and importing tables to your model navigation properties should be created automatically (your database must have correctly configured referential integrity - foreign keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation properties are simple in EF. The example below shows how a navigation property would look:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Foo` represents tableA and `Bar` represents tableB. They key word for the navigation property is virtual which enables lazy-loading by default. This is assuming you're using EF4.1 Code First.

**EDIT**

Off the top of my head, this should be a good starting template for you:

```
public class PointOfInterestContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<PointOfInterest> PointOfInterest { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<POITag> POITag { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }

    public override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // custom mappings go here
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    }
}

public class PointOfInterest
{
    // properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // etc...

    // navigation properties
    public virtual IEnumerable<POITag> POITags { get; set; }    
}

public class POITag
{
    // properties
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int PointOfInterestId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public virtual PointOfInterest PointOfInterest { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    // properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    // etc...

    // navigation properties
    public virtual IEnumerable<POITags> POITags { get; set; }    
}
```

Then you would implement the other logic in your business objects. The entities are supposed to be lightweight and at most should have data attributes. I prefer to use the fluent mappings through the OnModelCreating though.

Here are a few good references: 
[MSDN - EF 4.1 Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696172%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) 
[Code First Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: im getting a "The required property 'Foo' does not exist on type 'MyNamespace.Bar'.  In the Bar class i have a property <code>public virtual Foo Foo { get; set;}</code> On the entity model in the edmx file there is a navigation property on the Bar entity which says its an instance of Foo.  Do you know what that error could be?

Comment: How will this help if OP uses EDMX?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I assumed he was using code first since the EDMX takes care of navigation properties.

Comment: the c# classes are written first. Then i create the entity in the edmx file.  I have automatic code generation turned off because i need to extend base classes.

Comment: @MBU why are you combining code first and model first? I would suggest code first if you are looking for flexibility.

Comment: This design for how this stuff would work in our code was made by someone else so I'm not sure why it was a combination.  And its kind of too late to do any big changes because this projects supposed to be done soon and there's a lot of other things that we haven't gotten to yet.

Comment: @MBU You can't use both together because they serve the same purpose. It should be easy enough to remove one and keep the other. It just depends what implementation you want to use.

Comment: I think it would have to be code first since we need to extend base classes and have custom methods in the classes. Are there any good tutorials on how set that up and how to do types that have collections of other entity types?

Comment: @MBU see the updates in my answer. that should help you with getting started.